# Altering Postgres table to have unique with constraint when duplicates records alredy exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-orm

We are using Django ORM backed by Postgres.

We have some table ("foo") with duplicate records that we want to alter and add some unique constraint so no duplication will be inserted.

In order to do so, we first need to delete the duplicated records and than add the unique constraint (otherwise the add constraint using alter table will fail because of the records duplication).

I wanted to run the following transaction in order to implement the flow described above -

```
BEGIN WORK;

DELETE FROM foo
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT id
    FROM 
        (SELECT id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY a1, a2
        ORDER BY  id ) AS row_num
        FROM foo ) t
        WHERE t.row_num > 1 );

LOCK TABLE foo IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;

DELETE FROM foo
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT id
    FROM 
        (SELECT id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY a1, a2
        ORDER BY  id ) AS row_num
        FROM foo ) t
        WHERE t.row_num > 1 );

ALTER TABLE "foo" ADD CONSTRAINT "some_constaint_name" UNIQUE ("a1", "a2");

COMMIT WORK;
```

- the delete part is here twice in order to minimize the time the lock will be acquired
- the lock is in order to block more duplication insertion between the delete and the alter statement).

However, this fails on
"cannot ALTER TABLE "foo" because it has pending trigger events", which makes sense I guess.

If so, what can I do in order to achieve the uniqueness I desire?
Copying the data to a new table is not possible due to the amount of data the table has...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to see the purpose of the locks or of the two delete statements, but to execute the triggers right away, run this before the `ALTER TABLE`:

```
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE;
```

Comment: the lock is in order to block more duplication insertion between the delete and the alter statement). The delete is in order to remove duplication, otherwise adding the constraint will fail.

Comment: I think the better way to do this is to run *one* `DELETE`, then try to create a unique constraint. If that happens to fail because of a race condition, repeat the whole process.

Comment: We ended up doing exactly that (worked on first try)